# Interrupt repeater to add advertisement and continue with the repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

Between the comments and blog entries i want to add some stuff to earn some money :D 
I use

```
<asp:repeater>
</asp:repeater>
```

To write out all the blog entries.
Is it possible in some way to interrupts the repeater to be able to write out the code for the ad-banner?
For example run 3 entries, then add some code for the advertisement and continue with another 3 rows of blog entries?
 And so on...

Comment: Just a quick idea: You could repeat a repeater and your banner.

Comment: Have a counter and when it reaches a threshold put the advert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible out-of-the-box, but there is a quite simple workaround.

Add a Panel in the end of your repeater ItemTemplate, put the ad inside it, and set it's Visible attribute to be "<%# Container.DataItemIndex == 3 %>" or whatever,

Comment: Could also display an ad every `n` posts with `<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 5 == 0 %>` (where n = 4, 4+1=5).